# Reset Mac Login Password Using Shell Script Without putting Old/Existing Password (forgotten password)

Tags: macos, bash, password, script, user-account

I'd like to script password changes where I don't know the existing admin password and tried unsuccessfully:

```
dscl . -passwd /Users/[user short name] [password]
```

When I hit enter, it still asks the existing password to change with the new one.

and this script also need to existing/old password to reset:

```
username=$1
oldpwd=$2
newpwd=$3

dscl . -passwd /Users/"$username" $oldpwd $newpwd
security set-keychain-password -o $oldpwd -p  $newpwd "/Users/$username/Library/Keychains/login.keychain"
```

I tried to use the normal script from the internet, but all scripts are still asking the old/existing password to proceed.

Is that possible to create a script that can bypass to put the old/existing password? I need to do this for my users (above 500 users).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141334/discussion-on-question-by-caine0027-reset-mac-login-password-using-shell-script).

Answer (score 1):

Yes - make a new user with a known admin password, then your scripting challenge becomes easy. Do you have one specific build of MacOS that you need help?

Apple documents most of the recent password reset processes pretty well, so I would start here and then once you have an admin / sudo password that works, we can revisit any script hangups you have.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202860

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad Caine0027 had this in mind and shared it with us.
I was able to replicate this with bash script `.sh` file, running from Intune.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

username=$1
oldpwd=$2
newpwd=$3

dscl . -passwd /Users/"$username" $oldpwd $newpwd
security set-keychain-password -o $oldpwd -p  $newpwd "/Users/$username/Library/Keychains/login.keychain"

status=$?

if [ $status == 0 ]; then
    echo "Password was changed successfully."

elif [ $status != 0 ]; then
    echo "An error was encountered while attempting to change the password. /usr/bin/dscl exited $status."

fi

exit $status
```

Even though that status check is irrelevant for this, since Intune is not picking up that value into device status, It seem to work If I know the password of course

Although I would need password + salt into hash or something else to secure the password.

Chris_fast was writing a good [script](https://community.jamf.com/t5/jamf-pro/changing-the-adm-password-by-script/m-p/157323) but I have't tested it yet for I don't understand it all together.